# Getting azure ad users list for specific application with graph api

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

In the azure graph I have a list of users, some of which can be assigned to enterprise applications(my registered app). How can we get users of a specific application using the graph api(with Postman)?

with this api i get list of all users without depending on application application

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

also tried find some information about applications from users license by id, but still no success

```
POST /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/assignLicense
```

and from application information

```
GET /applications/{id}
```

i have a full stack of permissions for graph api for users, directories, application both for the delegated user and for the application so this is definitely not the problem.

I hope for your help, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this api below to list all users or groups assigned to an app:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/{id}/appRoleAssignedTo
```

For more information about this api, please refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/approleassignment-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http).
[image]

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you! I used my application`s object-id for {id} param and get 
 array with values witch include get principal id. Then i got all users for app with in /v1.0/users